# Rails - Integration between databases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, integration

I want to do an integration between my local database and my Heroku app.
The integration must read my local database with a query and send the information to my Heroku app, there, the information will be processed.

Does anybody did that?
Is there any guide for doing that?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You can do API then call them from your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably lots of ways to do this. Perhaps the easiest and least, technical solution way to do this would be to write to a csv file the data you want and then upload the csv file into your heroku app where a rake task would read and parse the csv.

A cleaner solution would be to use something like Httparty to post the data from your local app to an API endpoint on your Heroku app. The endpoint controller could then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: Thanks Isaiah, i will try the Httparty solutuion. Sadly, my cliente doesn't want to upload files anymore, he wants to have his data sync all the time

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Np! I will say that it's a little odd to have a running integration between a local and production environment. Maybe you should just push up your local environment to heroku as well? But if you need one going forward, what you might want is to use something like ngrok or pagekite to expose your local environment to the outside world, and then write a chron job (or I think they have scheduler dynos) on your heroku app that runs a rake task that hits an API endpoint on your local app at a set interval (so the reverse of my previous answer).

Comment: Isaiah, I created a new Rails application with two databases. One is the client database and the other is my Heroku database
First I execute a query in my client, aftes find results, create the connection with Heroku and puts in a temp table
This helped a lot!
http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/managing-multiple-databases-in-a-single-rails-application/

Thank you for your help :)